# How to compute median value of sales figures?

Tags: median

In MySQL while there is an AVG function, there is no Median. So I need to create a way to compute Median value for sales figures.

I understand that Median is the middle value. However, it isn't clear to me how you handle a list that isn't an odd numbered list. How do you determine which value to select as the Median, or is further computation needed to determine this? Thanks!

Comment: If there is an even number of values, you take the average of the two values in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of including an explicit ORDER BY statement:

SELECT t1.val as median_val

FROM (

SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as `row_number`, d.val
  FROM data d,  (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  WHERE 1
  -- put some where clause here
  ORDER BY d.val
) as t1,

(
  SELECT count(*) as total_rows
  FROM data d
  WHERE 1
  -- put same where clause here
) as t2
WHERE 1
AND t1.row_number=floor(total_rows/2)+1;